# Acrobat Database Connectivity (ADBC) for javascript

Tags: acrobat

Is it possible to establish ADBC if ODBC is not installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as of Acrobat 9, [ADBC requires ODBC](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/JS_Dev_Databases.84.2.html).

> The Acrobat extensions to JavaScript provides an ODBC-compliant object model called Acrobat Database Connectivity (ADBC), which can be used in document-level scripts to connect to a database for the purposes of inserting new information, updating existing information, and deleting database entries. ADBC provides a simplified interface to ODBC, which it uses to establish a connection to a database and access its data, and supports the usage of SQL statements for data access, update, deletion, and retrieval.
>
> Thus, **a necessary requirement to the usage of ADBC is that ODBC must be installed on a client machine running a Microsoft Windows operating system.** In addition, ADBC does not provide security measures with respect to database access; it is assumed that the database administrator will establish and maintain the security of all data.

(emphasis added)